# StackExchange.Redis installation makes the project require newer version of system.net.http

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I have a small library project used by some web project. The project has a reference to System.net.http version 4.0.0 with resolved path C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Net.Http.dll

Than I decided to install StackExchange.Redis nuget package and after installation I noticed that the same project has now a reference to system.net.http version 4.2.0 with resolved apth to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib

This of course caused some rune time errors in the web projects which reference this library project, since they are still using 4.0.0.

The nuget package does have some dependencies, but nothing to do with the system.net.http assembly. Also when I compare the project file, app.config and package.config file, I don't see any change regarding this (just new references to other assemblies).

My questions are: 
Is this 'upgrade' of this assembly caused by any of the new referenced libraries? And how can I determine which one? 
How should I fix this? Make a hint path in the web projects to the new path? Does this path exists on other visual studio installations as well?

Comment: I am facing the same issue - did you find a solution?

Comment: no, could locate what was causing it. the solution was placing assembly references in the web.config pointing 4.0.0 to the new 4.2.0